# I want to get all permission for another application from my application

Tags: android, permissions

my application is getting forced close. please help me. I want to get permissions list that are being used by application in my mobile.

```
package com.permissions;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class GetPermissions extends Activity {

TextView tvShow;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_get_permissions);

    tvShow = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvshow);
    tvShow.setText(PackageManager.GET_PERMISSIONS);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.get_permissions, menu);
    return true;
}

}
```

Comment: you will find the missing rights written in your logcat ..

Answer (score 1):

First of All, the line `tvShow.setText(PackageManager.GET_PERMISSIONS);` doesn't helps you. It only gets you the permissions you given in the Manifest file. The requiored permissions, which is not declared in manifest file will be shown in the LogCat Error.

If you want to get the Permissions that are used in your app, then the code from [here](http://www.basic4ppc.com/android/forum/threads/getting-the-manifest-permissions-of-an-app.11350/) will help

```
final Intent mainIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null);
mainIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
final List pkgAppsList = getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(mainIntent, 0);

for (Object obj : pkgAppsList) {
  ResolveInfo resolveInfo = (ResolveInfo) obj;
  PackageInfo packageInfo = null;
  try {
    packageInfo = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(resolveInfo.activityInfo.packageName, PackageManager.GET_PERMISSIONS);
  } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
  }

  String[] requestedPermissions = packageInfo.requestedPermissions;
}
```